# how can i get information from a google form and put it into a google sheet using google scripts app app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm very new to this. Have a background in super old coding qbasic/dos.

What I want to do is the following:

A customer submits my google form.
I have a google script within that form.
How do I declare the variables from their answers they wrote in that form?
Then I want to put that information into a specific sheet (I KNOW HOW TO DO THIS PART, but got no clue how to get the variables from google form)

So far I am here: (ps I have trigger activate run on formsubmit)

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var wannavalue = e.values[1];
  var ship =SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Vhh_HPCmbWWIymOJoaLBZOiTpGC8E0UOK1ORMVJtpoQ");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("AVAILABLES");


  Logger.log(wannavalue);

{
```

The Error keeps coming up as the following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")
>   Dismiss

Just want to declare those variables from the google form and put them where they need to go!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The "event object" `e` is undefined.  That means that you are running the code from the code editor.  If you run the code from the code editor, then the Form was not submitted, and no event object was passed in.  There was no event.  The only way there can be an event is if the Form was submitted.

Comment: The event object for a script bound to a form is different than the event object for a script bound to a spreadsheet. The form's version has no `values` parameter: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3